# Redis nextjs close redis connection

Tags: redis, next.js

I am using `iron-session` to handle the sessions on my nextjs app, but some of the sessions were too big so I created only a key with the `iron-session` and getting the result using Redis.

I have a really basic connector

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { logError } from './logger';

const client = createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL });

client.on('error', (error) => {
    logError(error)
});

export async function connect() {
    if (!client.isOpen) await client.connect()
    return client
}
```

But I have a lot `Socket closed unexpectedly` error, should be because I am never calling the `quit` function.

I do not know if this is a big issue for the Redis server to have this kind of error all the time, if not, I could just ignore this it.
The other solution would be to call `quit` at the end of each my `api` and `getServerSideProps` which are using sessions from Redis, but I do not find it spotless, it will be a lot of code and complexity

Comment: Where is the program been run on? Could you elaborate runtime environment and is it serverless? Maybe its only invoked when called. How about reestablishing connection (retry connectivity) upon connection loss?

Comment: This is because your redis connection is trying to connect in client side as well. Client side does not support redis connections, you have to initialize/connect to the redis only in the server side.

Comment: Redis is onli call on API routes not on client side

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Node.js: Closing all Redis clients on shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895063/node-js-closing-all-redis-clients-on-shutdown)?

Comment: @juliomalves thanks but `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` are not called

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure to execute `client.connect()` after `client.on('error')`

From the code you have, it has potential `client.connect()` called without `client.on('error')` to be registered first. You can see this thread about handling error.

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1985#issuecomment-1116865925